# Cannot createRecord with mutable array attribute

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, pouchdb

I am trying to make it so that every new collection record that is created, has a products attribute, whose value is an empty mutable array.

I got a model defined in /collection.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
      name: DS.attr('string'),
      products: DS.hasMany('product'),
      rev: DS.attr('string')
});
```

and a route in /view-collections.js. In the route, createCollection is an action that creates a record of a collection locally (I use PouchDB which uses Ember Data functionality). I am having trouble at the line where createRecord is called. After some console logs and creating a collection myself, I realized that the saved collection record does not include a products attribute, just name and rev, it is like the line  "products: []" gets ignored.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
    return this.store.findAll('collection');
  },

  titleToken: 'Collections',

  actions: {
    createCollection() {
      let route = this,
          controller = this.get('controller');

      let collection = this.store.createRecord('collection', {
        name: controller.get('newName'),
        products: []
      });
      return collection.save().then(function() {
        controller.set('newName', '');
        //route.transitionTo('products.product.collections', product);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Instead of

```
products: []
```

and

```
products: Ember.A([])
```

of which, both seem like they dont get executed, I also tried all of the following

```
products: DS.MutableArray([])
products: DS.ManyArray
products: DS.MutableArray
products: DS.ManyArray([])
```

which give me errors. Finally, on my view-collections.hbs

```
{{#link-to 'products' class="button"}}
    Back to products
    {{/link-to}}
      {{input type="text" class="new-collection" placeholder="New Collection" value=newName insert-newline="createCollection" }}
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm new-collection-button" {{action "createCollection"}}
        disabled={{disabled}}>Add</button>

{{#each model as |collection|}}
        <div>{{collection.name}} {{collection.products}} {{collection.id}}
        </div>
    {{/each}}
```

where I print all the info of all collections, it actually finds an object for {{collection.products}} and prints the following for every collection.

```
<DS.PromiseManyArray:ember498>
```

Any idea on what this last part is and how I can write that "products: []", line in the route, is welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without providing value for `product`, you can `createRecord` for collection. this will work.
if you want to include product record then don't provide it while creating the record, you can use `pushObject` after creating the record.

```
let collection = this.store.createRecord('collection', {
        name: controller.get('newName')
      });
//createRecord for product
let product = this.store.createRecord('product');
collection.get('products').pushObject(product);
```